# phpmailer gives error after applying on my website

Tags: php, email, gmail, phpmailer

I am facing the problem of applying PHP mailer on my website which is currently live.I use katyaweb.com for my website hosting.
I have configured and tested PHP mailer on my local machine which runs  WAMP.
It works pretty well on my local host, The message can be sent successfully and the receiver receives the message as well.

But when I am applying it on my website 'projectmedussa.com', it gives a big error.I don't know why? I would be very grateful if anyone could help me out.

Thank you,

Here is my code.

```
<?php

require 'smptmail/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                               // Enable verbose debug        output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP    authentication
$mail->Username = 'medusa123.test@gmail.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = '*******';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to

$mail->setFrom('medusa123.test@gmail.com', 'Medusa');
//$mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
$mail->addAddress('mahdi2.samim@gmail.com');               // Name is optional

$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'You successfully registered to medusa website';
$mail->Body    = 'this is testing message from meudusa123.test@gmail.com';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is to test whether the phpmailer work or not!';

if(!$mail->send()) {
   echo 'Message could not be sent.';
   echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
 } else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
?>
```

I get the following error

```
2017-03-25 07:42:22 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP 
10sm5875220wrz.44 - gsmtp 2017-03-25 07:42:22 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO 
projectmedussa.com 2017-03-25 07:42:22 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com   at   your service, [91.148.168.54] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH 250-
 ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-PIPELINING 250-CHUNKING 250 SMTPUTF8 2017-03-25    07:42:22 
 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN 2017-03-25 07:42:23 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 
VXNlcm5hbWU6 2017-03-25 07:42:23 CLIENT -> SERVER: 
bWVkdXNhMTIzLnRlc3RAZ21haWwuY29t 2017-03-25 07:42:23 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 
UGFzc3dvcmQ6 2017-03-25 07:42:23 CLIENT -> SERVER: bWVkdXNhMTIzNDU= 2017-03-25 
07:42:23 SERVER -> CLIENT: 534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and 
534-5.7.14 then try again. 534-5.7.14 Learn more at 534 5.7.14 
https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 10sm5875220wrz.44 - gsmtp 2017-  03-
25 07:42:23 SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 534-5.7.14 Please log in via 
your web browser and 534-5.7.14 then try again. 534-5.7.14 Learn more at 534 
5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 10sm5875220wrz.44 -   gsmtp 
2017-03-25 07:42:23 SMTP Error: Could not authenticate. 2017-03-25 07:42:23 
CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT 2017-03-25 07:42:23 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 closing 
connection 10sm5875220wrz.44 - gsmtp 2017-03-25 07:42:23 SMTP connect()  failed. 
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting Message could not be
 sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. 
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

Comment: Never share original credential publicly

Comment: This question has been asked and answered many times. Read what the error says.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHPMailer SMTP Gmail authentification error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30185611/phpmailer-smtp-gmail-authentification-error)

Comment: I solved the issue . Wrong configuration of the server caused the problem and errors, I fixed it out.Now,  email can be sent to the users successfully and  I can receive email from our users as well.